# Do not show ellipsis when not needed in search results

Tags: bug, search

When doing a search, the results page shows an ellipsis when it is not needed. For instance:

[image: search results]

The message of that answer is shorter than the text overflow limit, which means the ellipsis (...) should not be shown.

[image: answer]

Comment: I think this is a very rare edge case. Not saying it's a valid bug, but most posts which do not go over that limit will probably be deleted.

Comment: @Emracool I see it quite often when I use some search queries for NAA answers. When it has no ellipsis, I could quicker see it should be flagged than when it has the ellipsis (there could be more info in the rest of the answer)

Comment: Isn't the real issue that the post you're showing isn't an answer?  I'll take a peek at the search code breaks (it happens on the elastic side), but posts being that short isn't good either.

Comment: @NickCraver yes, indeed. As I said, I often use these search queries to find these NAA answers.

Comment: @WouterJ I changed how this works slightly on very short posts, can you try your normal searches and see if you're still seeing it occur anywhere?

Comment: @NickCraver sorry, I still have the same problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0EPHY.png

Comment: @WouterJ can't repro here, see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j1fSa.png): no ellipsis on short answer. Can you please give your exact search query to reproduce this?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd another example: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22can%20you%20give%22%20is%3aa then the "A: Django: API call issue while running on gunicorn" result by Kevin_cl

Comment: Hmm... see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Can+you+give+more+detail+about+your+question.%22) - same answer, no ellipsis. This means it's added only when using the `is:answer` search operator. @Nick for your attention as well. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd making it crazier, adding `is:a` here doesn't make it show the ellipsis: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Can+you+give+more+detail+about+your+question.%22+is%3Aa

Comment: Oh my. [another one, without is:answer at all](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Can+you+give+more+detail+about%22) and showing ellipsis - well, now I assume it's showing only when there's more than one search result.

Comment: @NickCraver ping, in case you missed the previous replies.

Comment: @NickCraver Another ping, just in case ;)